# Make parallel calls http get or post calls in angular 2

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http

How to make parallel calls HTTP get or post calls in angular 2?

I have 2 service calls on the response of one callus have to make another call.

Could some suggest me how to call make these parallel calls with error handling scenarios?

Comment: Please post code snippet if you any.

Comment: So this wouldn't be parrallel calls, but sequential, right? Use the switchMap RxJS operator.

Answer (score 5):

If your service is `Observable` based instead of `Promise` you can do `forkJoin`. It runs all observable sequences in parallel.

For RxJS version < 6

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

Make sure to `import forkJoin` from `rxjs` library

```
Observable.forkJoin(myService.getCall(),
            myService.postCall(),
            ...)
            .subscribe((res) => {
              res[0] // this is first service call response,
              res[1] // this is second service call response
              ...
});
```

Or if you want it to be sequential do the first call and on complete call second.

```
myService.getCall().subscribe((response) => {
  // handle response
}, (error) => {
  // handle error here
}, () => {
  // this is complete block and it is triggered when obervable is complete
  myService.postCall();
}
```

**EDIT:**  for RxJS 6 and above `forkJoin` has changed

Service:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { forkJoin, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private  http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getAndPost(): Observable<any> {
    return forkJoin(
      this.http.get('/api/get'),
      this.http.post('/api/post')
    );
  }
}
```

Component:

```
firstResponse: any;
secondResponse: any;

constructor(private myService: MyService) {
}

myFunction(): void {
  this.myService.getAndPost().subscribe((res) => {
    this.firstResponse = res[0],
    this.secondResponse = res[1]
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Comment: Helped me a lot.

Comment: No probs, glad I could help ;)